# Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: Extension missing: openssl

Tags: php, xampp, phpmailer

I search in stackoverflow for more than 2hours (for @FRed)

So I use XAMPP and I created a contact form with sending mail and it worked perfectly. But now, when I try to complete the form and submit, I get "Message could not be sent.
Mailer Error: Extension missing: openssl" message. I have openssl extension enabled. I don't know what is the problem. Check stackoverflow and google for 2 hours. Somebody know what is the problem?

Comment: Do you really see openssl extension when running `php -m`?

Comment: @Justinas where can I check that?

Comment: Run this command in CLI